# Password-checking with prolog

Tags: passwords, prolog, grammar

I want to write a prolog program which tells me if a password fulfills the rules, which are:

- the password must contain a letter(a-z),
- a number(0-9),
- a double letter (aa,ll,ww etc.),
- must start with a letter (a, aa, c etc.),
- must be at least 6 characters long

How can I do that? And how should I "ask questions" after that? (Q1:Is this password correct? Q2:Is it long enough?)

Thank you for your answer in advance. It's very important and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Does "aaaaa0" really qualify?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd go with something like that, but there are maybe far better solutions using DCG or something else :

```
contains_letter(Password) :- wildcard_match('*[a-zA-Z]*', Password).

contains_number(Password) :- wildcard_match('*[0-9]*', Password).

contains_double_letter(Password) :-
    (between(65, 90, Letter) ; between(97, 122, Letter)),
    append([_, [Letter, Letter], _], Password),
    !.

starts_with_letter(Password) :- wildcard_match('[a-zA-Z]*', Password).

long_enough(Password) :-
    length(Password, Length),
    Length >= 6.

check_everything(Password) :-
    contains_letter(Password),
    contains_number(Password),
    contains_double_letter(Password),
    starts_with_letter(Password),
    long_enough(Password).
```

Usage would be :

```
?- check_everything("password_to_test").
```

or just one of the criterias :

```
?- long_enough("password_to_test").
```

Note that it uses a swi-pl predicate `wildcard_match/2` and that I do not know if it is available in other implementations.
I hope this can be of some help !

Note that `contains_letter/1`, `contains_number/1` and `starts_with_letter/1` can all be combined into one `wildcard_match/2` btw :

```
starts_with_letter_has_number(Password) :-
    wildcard_match('[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*', Password).
```

Comment: Yes, it's a big help, it's working properly. Thank you very much for the help. :)

Comment: I added a possible simplification btw.

Comment: I have one more question. I want every double letter to be counted as one. How can I do that?